# Branching process expectancy given an initial condition

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Given a branching process {$X_n$} with offspring probabilities $p_0 = 1/6, p_1 = 1/3,$ and $p_2 = 1/2$, find ${E[X_2|X_0 = 10]}$. I know that $E[X_n|X_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}\mu$. I tried stating that $E[X_2|X_0 = 10] = \mu E[X_1|X_0 = 10] = \mu^2E[X_0|X_0 = 10] = 10\mu^2$, but I don't know if this is correct, and if it is, I don't know how to state it "elegantly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "iterated expectations" and I assume there is also some memoryless-ness or Markov property in the system.  Iterated expectations gives $$E[X_2|X_0=10]=E[E[X_2|X_1, X_0=10]|X_0=10]$$ and the Markov-type property would imply $$E[X_2|X_1, X_0=10]=E[X_2|X_1]$$ so that information about time $0$ is irrelevant given the state at time $1$.

---

In general for random variables $W,Z$ we have the *iterated expectations* formula: 
$$E[W]=E[E[W|Z]]$$ and if we want to condition on some event $\mathcal{A}$ then this formula is modified to 
$$E[W|\mathcal{A}] = E[E[W|Z,\mathcal{A}]|\mathcal{A}]$$
In your case 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}&=\{X_0=10\}\\
W &= X_2\\
Z &= X_1
\end{align}

Comment: I see, thank you. Where can I find a proof of $E[W|A] = E[E[W|Z,A]|A]$?

Comment: Define a new probability measure $\mu(\cdot|\mathcal{A})$ and it follows from the existing iterated expectations formula.

Comment: Assuming PDFs are well defined you can say $$E[W|A] = \int_w w f_{W|A}(w|A)dw = \int_w w \left(\int_z f_{W|A}(w|A, Z=z)f_{Z|A}(z|A)dz \right)dw$$ Also, I did a google search and find similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations